# jQuery Mobile changePage from native Android menu item with PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've created a web app using jQuery Mobile. Works great. I've even managed to build a working APK using PhoneGap.

One thing I am having trouble with:

How do I perform a `$.mobile.changePage()` on the click event of a native menu item?Specifically, I press the menu button on the device, it shows me the option I created, how do I link the click of that option to a `changePage()` in jQM?

I've created the menu item in the xml file in Eclipse and, in my searching, I've found Java code associated with onOptionsItemSelected(), which I think is close to what I am looking for, but I have zero experience with Java. I can't even install Minecraft mods properly. I guess I am basically wondering how to execute Javascript in the onclick of a native menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

You'll need to ensure that you've included cordova.js in your code in order to use this event

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events

Comment: Just to clarify, because I may be wrong in my assumption, but this will fire off any time the device's menu button is pressed, right? I need to catch the click of a specific option from the menu that results when said menu button is pressed.

Comment: Sorry, I've completely misread your question - long day! I imagine you'll want to call this.sendJavascript in your onOptionsItemSelected() and pass it the relevant js function name.